# Dump HTTP requests in WildFly 8

Tags: logging, wildfly, wildfly-8

To debug HTTP requests during development, **I would like my WildFly 8 application server to dump HTTP requests, including request method and headers, to a log file**. `server.log` would be fine.

In the sources of WildFly's HTTP subsystem, I found [RequestDumpingHandler](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/server/handlers/RequestDumpingHandler.java) and the corresponding logging category `io.undertow.request.dump`

However, I cannot figure out, how to install that header so that it is applied for all requests served by my application (a WAR with some static resources and JAX-RS handler).

The corresponding documentation page ([Undertow web subsystem configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Undertow+%28web%29+subsystem+configuration)) doesn't really explain handlers. There is a `<handler>` element in the configuration section

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:2.1">
    ...
    <profile>
        ...
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.1">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            <!-- <dump-request /> ?? or something?-->
        </handlers>
        <filters>
            <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/8"/>
            <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
        </filters>
        </subsystem>
        ...
    </profile>
    ...
</server>
```

but as far as I can tell, only `<file>` and proxy are expected there(?).

**How can I log full details of incoming HTTP requests in WildFly?** I know I could install some logging mechanism at the JAX-RS layer, but I would like to have one dump mechanism that handles both REST API calls and statically served resources.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You would need to add RequestDumpingHandler to your handler chain.

As part of wildfly 8.1, that is not yet possible in a friendly way.

This is improved in 8.2 and 9 so you will be able to configure this by adding something like this:

```
<host name="default-host" >
     .....
     <filter-ref name="request-dumper"/>
</host>
....
<filters>
    ...
    <filter name="request-dumper" class-name="io.undertow.server.handlers.RequestDumpingHandler" module="io.undertow.core" />
</filters>
```

in 8.1 only option now would be to add ServletExtension http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.2.0/#servlet-extensions

that would add this RequestDumpingHandler to outer chain.

FWIW 8.2 release is almost ready, so you could wait for it or just build sources for 8.x branch.

To add above config via CLI, you can use:

```
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=filter/custom-filter=request-dumper:add(class-name="io.undertow.server.handlers.RequestDumpingHandler", module="io.undertow.core")
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/filter-ref=request-dumper:add
```

And to remove config after debugging:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/filter-ref=request-dumper:remove
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=filter/custom-filter=request-dumper:remove
```

Comment: Is there a way to dump as well the request/response body with this handler, please?

Comment: @ctomc Any way to print the content of the http request and the response?

Comment: @tarilabs did you figure out the solution for this?

Comment: @Zeus hi, it's been a long time, but IIRC I needed also to perform other custom operations for the request/response and I ended up writing my own custom handlers and not the default ones.

Comment: How to add this filter using jboss-cli?

Comment: Confirmed also in Wildfly 11.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

On Wildfly 9 and 10.1.0, it works just by adding

```
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
            <server name="default-server">
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <access-log/>
            </host>
            </server>
            </sub-system>
```

Comment: Note that access-log just writes the requests in an access.log file. It does not log the headers or body.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of people asking how to get the entire HTTP body logged out, not just the headers.

It seems an answer exists: https://8bitplatoon.blogspot.com/2017/02/dumping-http-requests-and-responses-in.html

In short, if that link doesn't survive, a simple addition to your standalone.xml will do the trick:

```
<system-properties>
  <property name="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump" value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```

I added this after the `<extensions>...</extensions>` and before `<management>...</management>`, restarted wildfly, and was able to get complete HTTP bodies in my server logs (server.log in my case).

This does not interact with or depend on the Undertow "request dumper" at all as far as I can tell, you can do one, the other, or both.

Comment: not working with me on wildfly 10, I restarted wildfly as well

Comment: Are you putting it in the right location per the (still valid) link in my comment? (Option 2)

Comment: Not working with JBoss 7.3 here. I'm setting the property with the cli and reloaded.