# Logging request and response in one place with JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a RESTEasy web server with lot of methods. I want implement logback to track all requests and responses, but I don't want add `log.info()` to every methods.

Maybe there's way to catch requests and responses in one place and log it. Maybe something like a filter on HTTP request process chain on RESTEasy.

```
@Path("/rest")
@Produces("application/json")
public class CounterRestService {

    //Don't want use log in controler every method to track requests and responces
    static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CounterRestService.class); 

    @POST
    @Path("/create")
    public CounterResponce create(@QueryParam("name") String name) {
        log.info("create "+name)
        try {
            CounterService.getInstance().put(name);
            log.info("responce data"); // <- :((
            return new CounterResponce();
        } catch (Exception e){
            log.info("responce error data"); // <- :((
            return new CounterResponce("error", e.getMessage());
        }    
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/insert")
    public CounterResponce create(Counter counter) {
        try {
            CounterService.getInstance().put(counter);
            return new CounterResponce();
        } catch (Exception e){
            return new CounterResponce("error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Have you considered name binding filters?

Comment: I think, I found right direction on https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can create filters and easily bind them to the endpoints you need to log, keeping your endpoints lean and focused on the business logic.

### Defining a name binding annotation

To bind filters to your REST endpoints, JAX-RS provides the meta-annotation [`@NameBinding`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/NameBinding.html) and it can be used as following:

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface Logged { }
```

### Logging the HTTP request

The `@Logged` annotation will be used to decorate a filter class, which implements [`ContainerRequestFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html), allowing you to handle the request:

```
@Logged
@Provider
public class RequestLoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        // Use the ContainerRequestContext to extract information from the HTTP request
        // Information such as the URI, headers and HTTP entity are available
    }
}
```

The [`@Provider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html) annotation marks an implementation of an extension interface that should be discoverable by JAX-RS runtime during a provider scanning phase.

The [`ContainerRequestContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html) helps you to extract information from the HTTP request.

Here are methods from the [`ContainerRequestContext` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#method.summary) to get information from the HTTP request that can be useful for your logs:

- [`ContainerRequestContext#getMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#getMethod--): Get the HTTP method from the request.
- [`ContainerRequestContext#getUriInfo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#getUriInfo--): Get URI information from the HTTP request.
- [`ContainerRequestContext#getHeaders()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#getHeaders--): Get the headers from the HTTP request.
- [`ContainerRequestContext#getMediaType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#getMediaType--): Get the media type of the entity.
- [`ContainerRequestContext#getEntityStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#getEntityStream--): Get the entity input stream.

### Logging the HTTP response

For logging the response, consider implementing a [`ContainerResponseFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseFilter.html):

```
@Logged
@Provider
public class ResponseLoggingFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, 
                       ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        // Use the ContainerRequestContext to extract information from the HTTP request
        // Use the ContainerResponseContext to extract information from the HTTP response
    }
}
```

The [`ContainerResponseContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseContext.html) helps you to extract information from the HTTP response.

Here are some methods from the [`ContainerResponseContext` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseContext.html#method.summary) to get information from the HTTP response that can be useful for your logs:

- [`ContainerResponseContext#getStatus()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseContext.html#getStatus--): Get the status code from the HTTP response.
- [`ContainerResponseContext#getHeaders()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseContext.html#getHeaders--): Get the headers from the HTTP response.
- [`ContainerResponseContext#getEntityStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseContext.html#getEntityStream--): Get the entity output stream.

### Binding the filters to your endpoints

To bind the filter to your endpoints methods or classes, annotate them with the  `@Logged` annotation defined above. For the methods and/or classes which are annotated, the filters will be executed:

```
@Path("/")
public class MyEndpoint {

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response myMethod(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        // This method is not annotated with @Logged
        // The logging filters won't be executed when invoking this method
        ...
    }

    @DELETE
    @Logged
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response myLoggedMethod(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        // This method is annotated with @Logged
        // The request logging filter will be executed before invoking this method
        // The response logging filter will be executed before invoking this method
        ...
    }
}
```

In the example above, the logging filters will be executed only for `myLoggedMethod(Long)` because it's annotated with `@Logged`.

### Additional information

Besides the methods available in [`ContainerRequestContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html) and [`ContainerResponseFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseFilter.html) interfaces, you can inject [`ResourceInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html) in your filters using [`@Context`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html):

```
@Context
ResourceInfo resourceInfo;
```

It can be used to get the [`Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) and the [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) which match with the requested URL:

```
Class<?> resourceClass = resourceInfo.getResourceClass();
Method resourceMethod = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
```

[`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) and [`HttpServletResponse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) are also available for injection:

```
@Context
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

@Context
HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse;
```

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35868654/1426227) for the types that can be injected with [`@Context`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html).

Comment: How to print ContainerResponseContext#getEntityStream() as this is output stream? 
And ContainerResponseContext#getEntity() returns an object which is org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.

Comment: You can print it in this way:
`BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(requestContext.getEntityStream());
        String payload = IOUtils.toString(stream, "UTF-8");
        logger.debug("Payload: " + payload);
        requestContext.setEntityStream(IOUtils.toInputStream(payload, "UTF-8"));`

Comment: this works for requestContext.getEntityStream (InputStream). How to do it for responseContext.getEntityStream (OutputStream) ?

Comment: You do not need the entity stream. Just use `responseContext.getEntity()`

Comment: Sometimes you have to love Java. Doing this with other languages is usually a one-line change to add a middleware module.

Answer (score 1):

Try Interceptors(not just vanilla EJB interceptors you can use CDI with that).

They are there for implementing Cross Cutting Concerns(aspects).

Answer (score 1):

For others using Jersey and trying to solve same problem, there is [org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.35/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/LoggingFeature.html) that can be used both on client or server. It logs request and response to java.util.logging.Logger.

Output can be bridged to slf4j with org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small library to easily log requests and responses : [JAX-RS Logging](https://github.com/Chavaillaz/jaxrs-logging)

It's available via Maven Central:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.chavaillaz</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-logging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and can be used with the annotation:

```
@Logged
```

to log the following message (with many MDC fields):

```
Processed [method] [URI] with status [status] in [duration]ms
```

and more options are available to log and filter request and response body.