# How can a JAX-RS web service only accept form parameters that are sent in the request body?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, forms

Let's say I have the following JAX-RS web service:

```java
public class HelloService {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMessage(@FormParam("name") String name) {
        return "Hello, " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

This web service will accept form parameters whether they're sent in the request body or sent in the URL (e.g. `http://foo.bar/baz?name=qux`).

Is there a way that I can configure the web service to only accept form parameters that are sent in the request body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a [`ContainerRequestFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html), as following:

```java
@Provider
public class QueryParametersFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        String query = requestContext.getUriInfo().getRequestUri().getQuery();

        if (query != null && !query.isEmpty()) {
            requestContext.abortWith(
                Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                        .entity("Parameters not allowed in the query string")
                        .build());
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation can be taylored to meet your needs.

**Important:** The above defined filter is *global*, that is, will be executed for all resource methods. To bind this filter to a set of methods, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33667568/1426227).

---

For dynamic binding, you also could try a [`DynamicFeature`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/DynamicFeature.html).