# How to measure the time taken for javax.ws.rs.client.Client to establish a connection?

Tags: java, rest, http, connection

we noticed that some of our requests to Azure are taking too long.

They told us that they don't appear to receive a request until much after we start the request. Given that, it would be good for us to be able to log how long it took to establish a connection to the remote host.

We are using javax.ws.rs.client.Client.

Does anyone know if there is a way to enable debug logging which would capture this metric or if we can get the metrics in some other way?

Comment: You can use `Actuator` and expose `httptrace` endpoint. Simple guide: 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuator-http

Comment: Also, if it is a Spring app, then you can add to your properties: `logging.level. javax.ws.rs.client=DEBUG` (or TRACE)

Comment: @RostyslavBarmakov It is a Spring app. I will try now this approach with logging level. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add interceptors in your request which will log the request and the response to the console and the time taken in that request will be logged in those requests. [how to add interceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666406/logging-request-and-response-in-one-place-with-jax-rs?answertab=active#tab-top) you can find the given post on stack over flow to see how you can do that.